# Load external scripts in Angular 2

Tags: angular, triggers, loading, external

Is there any option to load or trigger external scripts in component in Angular 2, but not append explicitly to head of document because that append every time when component is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly import and use external Script in your component like this :

```
import * as yourPreferedName from 'your-library';
yourPreferedName.method();
```

Comment: I have to load scripts that are hosted on web, not locally. When I insert them in index.html it load only once when app is started but when I change route and go back it won't start again.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Javascript files to the global scope via the apps[0].scripts property in .angular-cli.json. These will be loaded exactly as if you had added them in a  tag inside index.html.

This is especially useful for legacy libraries or analytic snippets.

```
"scripts": [
  "global-script.js",
],
```

You can also rename the output and lazy load it by using the object format:

```
"scripts": [
  "global-script.js",
  { "input": "lazy-script.js", "lazy": true },
  { "input": "pre-rename-script.js", "output": "renamed-script" },
],
```

Check the official angular-cli documentation here:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts